# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string SQL 17.1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some assistance if possible I'm trying to UPDATE the [Created On] and [Modified On], I've tried numerous ways of doing this via SOF (on here).

```
USE [DBName]
SET [Created On] = '2017-07-27  10:13:00',[Modified On] = '2017-07-27  10:19:00'
WHERE [Contract] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
GO
```

The two columns were set as (nvarchar(255), null - however, they have now changed to (datetime, null) - both ways have given me the same error. Know I know these two columns have date and time data that's been different, I cannot go in and correct it all as it's been handed over to me like this. The previous person knew how to manipulate the data, for the life of me I cannot!

I'm getting the following error repeatedly and I'm at a loss.

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v17.1 as an Administrator.

Could someone steer me in the right direction if possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run DBCC USEROPTIONS, what does dateformat and language say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ISO 8601 dates

```
USE [DBName]
SET [Created On] = '20170727 10:13:00',[Modified On] = '20170727 10:19:00'
WHERE [Contract] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
GO
```

Why? Implied DATEFORMAT set by language

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english

SELECT CAST('2017-07-27  10:13:00' AS datetime)

SET LANGUAGE british

SELECT CAST('2017-07-27  10:13:00' AS datetime)
```

Comment: You've fixed it! Thank you so much, after 4 hours of researching and trying a lot of different ways, I was about to put my head through the monitor! Owe you one! Thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used an `UPDATE` statement?

```
UPDATE t
    SET [Created On] = '2017-07-27 10:13:00',
        [Modified On] = '2017-07-27 10:19:00'
    WHERE [Contract] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Note:  This also replaces the double spaces with a single space.  If you have problem with the above, the formal definition for the datetime constant uses "T" instead of a space.

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, I apologise about double posting.

Comment: @LewisDee-Thomas . . . It doesn't work with the "T":  `'2017-07-27T10:13:00'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            UPDATE t 
            SET    Cast([CreatedOn] AS  DATETIME) = '2017-07-31  08:05:00', 
                cast([ModifiedOn] AS datetime) = '2017-07-31  15:25:00' 
            FROM   tablename t 
            WHERE  [Contract] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```